# Избежать замены цвета при использовании DayNight темы в Android

Tags: android, color, android-drawable, android-style, android-themes

Всем привет! Вопрос довольно краток - я использую у себя в проекте DayNight тему, и при использовании png иконки из drawable её цвет всегда меняется на чёрный. Как избежать этого?

Comment: Чтобы было проще понять, приведите примеры использования/скриншоты

Comment: Не лениться и задать стиль с параметрами для каждого элемента UI :)